# get session id from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables--answers, questions and tokens.

IN `tokens` I have `id, token, created_at, updated_at`.

IN `answers` i have `id, token (id), text, created_at, updated_at`

In `questions` - `id, text`

How can I get ID (from tokens) ? I do this way:

```
result=Answer.create(:question_id=>question.id,:token=>session[:token],:text=>params["answer_"+question.id.to_s])
```

I don't want `session[:token]`, it's pasted in table TOKENS (for example 23709274092107hdjshdsj) and I

> just need ID!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you're only storing the token in session. So you'd have to get the ID from the token so:

```
token = Token.find_by_token(session[:token])
result=Answer.create(:question_id=>question.id,:token=>token.id,:text=>params["answer_"+question.id.to_s])
```